# Запуск MPI программы без mpiexec/mpirun

Tags: c++, c, mpi, fortran

Какое поведение следует ожидать при запуске `MPI` программы без `mpiexec/mpirun`, но скомпилированной с помощью `MPI` компилятора? Специфицировано ли оно в стандарте?

Answer (score 1):

Об этом говорится в разделе `10.5.2` стандарта:

> A high-quality implementation will allow any process (including those
>   not started with a “parallel application” mechanism) to become an MPI
>   process by calling MPI_INIT. Such a process can then connect to other
>   MPI processes using the MPI_COMM_ACCEPT and MPI_COMM_CONNECT routines,
>   or spawn other MPI processes. MPI does not mandate this behavior, but
>   strongly encourages it where technically feasible.
>
> *Advice to implementors*. To start MPI processes belonging to the same
>   MPI_COMM_WORLD requires some special coordination. The processes must
>   be started at the “same” time, they must have a mechanism to establish
>   communication, etc. Either the user or the operating system must take
>   special steps beyond simply starting processes.
>
> When an application
>   enters MPI_INIT, clearly it must be able to determine if these special
>   steps were taken. If a process enters MPI_INIT and determines that no
>   special steps were taken (i.e., it has not been given the information
>   to form an MPI_COMM_WORLD with other processes) it succeeds and forms a 
>   singleton MPI program, that is, one in which MPI_COMM_WORLD has size 1.
>
> In some implementations, MPI may not be able to function without an
>   “MPI environ- ment.” For example, MPI may require that daemons be
>   running or MPI may not be able to work at all on the front-end of an MPP. In 
>   this case, an MPI implementation may either
>
> 1. Create the environment (e.g., start a daemon) or
> 2. Raise an error if it cannot create the environment and the environment has not been started independently.
>
> A high-quality
>   implementation will try to create a singleton MPI process and not
>   raise an error.
>
> *(End of advice to implementors.)*

То есть поведение не специфицировано, но рекомендовано в таком случае создавать коммуникатор размера 1 с нулевыми рангами процессов.